# How to create this chart in R or ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

Below is the code to create the data frame.

```
df <- data.frame (ID  = c('C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9','C10', 'C11', 'C12','C13', 'C14'),
                  A = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                  B = c(3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2)
                  )
```

Code to create the Category column:

```
df$Cat <- ifelse(df$A == 2 & df$B == 2, 'MID',
                 ifelse(df$A == 2 & df$B == 1, 'GONE', 
                        ifelse(df$A == 1 & df$B == 1, 'GONE', 
                               ifelse(df$A == 1 & df$B == 2, 'GONE', 
                                      ifelse(df$A == 2 |df$A == 1 & df$B == 3, 'UP',
                               
                               'NO')))))
```

The chart I need to create:
[image]

How can I create the chart I want from the data above? I have tried using Treemaps for this but I don't think that will work because it only allows comparing quantities by size in a fixed space. So what can be used? Any help will be greatly appreciate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is `geom_raster`.

To label the tiles as in your question, I would create an extra dataframe called `df_annotate` with all the `aes` specifies in that dataframe. In this case, you can control where the label appears on the graph (just set different `A` and `B` values as you like).

Here I set the values of `A` and `B` so that the labels appears at the position similar to your drawing. Remember to use `data = df_annotate` in the `geom_text()`.

### Prepare df_annotate for `geom_text`

```
library(tidyverse)

df_annotate <- df %>% group_by(Cat) %>% 
  summarize(sum_Cat = n()) %>% 
  mutate(sum_Cat_number = paste(sum_Cat, Cat), 
         A = c(1, 2, 1.5), 
         B = c(2, 2, 3))
```

### ggplot

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(B, A, fill = Cat)) + 
  geom_raster() +
  ylim(c(0.5, 3)) +
  geom_text(data = df_annotate, aes(B, A, label = sum_Cat_number), inherit.aes = F)
```

[image: geom_raster_df_annotate]

Comment: How can text appear only once in the area?  I have tried geom_text() but that makes the Cat 'GONE' appear 3 times in each of the boxes. I want GONE to apear once and this is the code I have tried so far.  df %>% ggplot(aes(B, A, fill = Cat)) + 
  geom_raster() +
geom_text(aes(label = Cat)) +
  ylim(c(0.5, 3))

Comment: See if my edited answer helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try a heatmap with ggplot2 using geom_tile()

```
ggplot(df, aes(A, B, fill= Cat)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "green", "red")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Cat), size=5)
```

[image]